# Hiding img tag inside div onClick() using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i tried to show and hide  img tag  in below code

```
<div id='userview_'<?php echo $userId; ?>>
    <img src="css/user/images/user1.svg">
</div>
```

i wrote jquery to show img like dis

```
var userId='<?php echo $userId; ?>';
jQuery('#userview_'+userId ' img').css('src','url(css/user/images/user1.svg) no repeat center');
```

but not working

and also i need to know hide this img tag (only) in onClick()

Comment: Why do you want to change the source of the image, instead of simply hiding the element via CSS `display: none`?

Comment: try using jQuery('img#userview') selector

Comment: `no repeat center` Are you trying to set background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found myself a method

```
 jQuery('#userview_'+userId , "'<img src=css/user/images/user1.svg>'").remove();
```

When i need to show it agin.. i used

```
jQuery('#userview_'+userId).append('<img src="css/user/images/user1.svg>">');
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Src is an attribute, so you need to do something like below and give proper image path,

```
var userId='<?php echo $userId; ?>';
jQuery('#userview_'+userId ' img').attr('src','css/user/images/user1.svg');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery('#userview_'+userId +' img')

                          ^^^^ you messed
```

use **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

### HTML

```
<div id='userview_33'>
    <img src="css/user/images/user1.svg" />
</div>
```

### JS

```
var userId = 33;

jQuery('#userview_' + userId +' img').attr('src', 'url(css/user/images/user3.svg) no repeat center');
```

Comment: Read to code again you're missing something in the div.

Comment: `<div id='userview_'<?php echo $userId; ?>>` should be `<div id='userview_<?php echo $userId; ?>'>`

Comment: @Bala Please check out the method i used..if any error in my method ..plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

First in your html place php tag inside of '' so like this `<div id='userview_<?php echo $userId; ?>'>`

Then you can do something like this

```
jQuery('#userview_'+userId+' img').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where You have:

```
var userId='< ? php echo $userId; ?>';

jQuery('#userview_'+userId ' img').css('src','url(css/user/images/user1.svg) no repeat center');
```

remember that the PHP script work only in PHP files. You can do like this: 
part of index.php

```
<div class="imgContainer"></div>
...
<script>var userId = <?php userId?> </script>
```

and in JS file:

```
jQuery('#userview_'+userId +' .imgContainer').css('src','url(css/user/images/user1.svg) no repeat center');
```

and if You want on click event:

```
jQuery('#userview_'+userId ' imgContainer').on('click', function(){
   /*some code*/
});
```

also walk thru this tutorial: http://try.jquery.com/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='userview_'<?php echo $userId; ?>>
    <img src="css/user/images/user1.svg" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="testclick">Click</a>
$('.testclick').click(function(){
var userId='<?php echo $userId; ?>';
    $('#userview_'+userId+' img').hide();
});
```